# Create a New Plone addon mrbob error

Tags: plone

I want to start developing of my first test addon. I have a problem on the basis of mr.bob. Any described ways have leaded to one result. [my documentation](http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/bobtemplates.plone/README.html)

log image
[image]

Check

> mrbob --help

do the same answer.

After I came to the conclusion the problem is in pre-installed Python2.7 with no worked mr.bobe and bobtemplates. **I do not know how to make a working set.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your traceback I guess mr.bob is not fully supporting Windows.

The `readline` module on Windows is not available. There's some alternatives like [pyreadline](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline).

Seems it's a know issue: see https://github.com/domenkozar/mr.bob/issues/49

Comment: you awesome! This solution to the problem. mr.bob is now working.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about mr.bob, but you could alternatively try adi.devgen (disclaimer: one of my add-ons). Install it with pip:

```
pip install adi.devgen
```

And then do:

```
devgen addOn yournamespace.youraddonname
```